# Where can I find files in various (common) extensions to test with my upload service?

Tags: file, testing, resources, tdd

I'm building a service that allows users to upload files. However, there are some file extensions that cause errors on the service, so I would like to try uploading most common file types to see which ones cause errors.

Where could I get the data set for testing?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't study the pattern of those extensions which result in error be a bit easier?

Comment: @蕭為元 The problem is I don't have enough info why some file extensions results in the errors. So I need to get as much as files as I can to study the pattern. Right now there are some errors with .rar, .zip but not .7z, some with .doc, but not .docx.